# How to retrieve sub documents in a Array from mongoDB using python script

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, subdocument

I am quite new to python and mongoDB and need to achieve this task.

I have a collection containing documents similar to the sample below.

```
{
        "_id" : 1900123,
        "name" : "AAAAA BBBB",
        "scores" : [
                {
                        "type" : "exam",
                        "score" : 44.51211101958831
                },
                {
                        "type" : "quiz",
                        "score" : 0.6578497966368002
                },
                {
                        "type" : "projectwork",
                        "score" : 93.36341655949683
                },
                {
                        "type" : "projectwork",
                        "score" : 49.43132782777443
                }
        ]
}
```

I am trying to read this collection in a python script. I am unable to retrieve the score from the sub document

```
cursor = students.find()

for doc in cursor:
        score1=doc["scores.2.score"];
        print("score1=",score1);
```

I am trying to find the lowest score for project work for each student, but i am unable to retrieve the score using index "scores.2.score".

Need some help to understand the retrieval method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pymongo's `find` method internally uses [`db.collections.find`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) which actually returns the cursor. When you iterate the cursor, you will get the individual documents. The documents returned will be represented in Python as a dictionary. So, in this case, `doc` is a dictionary. When you do

```
doc["scores.2.score"]
```

you are trying to fetch an item corresponding to the key `scores.2.score` in the `doc` dictionary. But as you see from the structure shown in the question, there is no such key called `scores.2.score`. Actually, when you do

```
doc["scores"]
```

you will get

```
[
    {
        "type": "exam",
        "score": 44.51211101958831
    },
    {
        "type": "quiz",
        "score": 0.6578497966368002
    },
    {
        "type": "projectwork",
        "score": 93.36341655949683
    },
    {
        "type": "projectwork",
        "score": 49.43132782777443
    }
]
```

which is a list and to get the second element from it, you will do

```
doc["scores"][2]
```

which will give you the dictionary

```
    {
        "type": "projectwork",
        "score": 93.36341655949683
    }
```

and to access `score` in it, you will do

```
doc["scores"][2]["score"]
```

and that will actually give you

```
93.36341655949683.
```